# Oracle converting pl/sql function to sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to convert this `pl/sql` to non `pl/sql` as we do not have access to functions and packages in oracle fusion, but currently I have no knowledge of `pl/sql` so I have no idea what this function does, can anyone help ?

```
FUNCTION numb(CNUMBER IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    TR          NUMBER;
    FR          NUMBER;
    fakat       VARCHAR2(20) := 'فقط';
    l_vc_ar_num VARCHAR2(32766);
  BEGIN

    IF cnumber > 999999999999.99 THEN
      RETURN 'Please enter a number less than 1 Trillion (1,000,000,000,000.00).';
    END IF;

    TR := TRUNC(CNUMBER, 0);

    FR := (ROUND(CNUMBER, 2) - TRUNC(CNUMBER, 0)) * 100;

    --if fractional part exists then do not append fakat
    --EXCEPTION IS 1 halala where we have to append fakat
    IF FR > 0 THEN

      IF TR = 0 THEN
        IF FR = 1 THEN
          l_vc_ar_num := fraction(FR) || ' ' || fakat;
        ELSE
          l_vc_ar_num := fraction(FR);
        END IF;
      ELSE

        l_vc_ar_num := anumb(TR) || ' و' || fraction(FR);

      END IF;
    ELSE

      l_vc_ar_num := anumb(TR) || ' ' || fakat;

    END IF;

    RETURN REPLACE(REPLACE(l_vc_ar_num, '   ', ' '), '  ', ' ');
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RETURN 'function numb. Others. Ex.' || SQLERRM;
  END;
```

Comment: Please describe your current issue. The code above doesn't use any advanced PL/SQL, this is a very basic code that looks more or less the same in any procedural language. And we do not know `anumb` and `fraction` definitions. And what is the purpose of this change from PL/SQL to SQL?

Comment: What SQL do you want as target? ANSI/ISO SQL PSM? (I.e. which dbms are you going to use?)

Comment: we can't make functions in oracle fusion, so I need to make alike of this function , same resulted column but in normal sql, for example ```if else``` would be ```case when```, currently i have no big knowledge of ```plsql``` so i really dont know what is ```anumb``` and ```fraction```

Comment: we use Oracle SQL

Comment: Since 12c you may declare functions locally by means of [`with plsql_declarations`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABFAFID): `with function numb(cnumber in number) return varchar2 ...`.

Comment: It looks like you could replace that with case expressions and `to_char()` and other built-in function calls. It depends a bit on what the missing functions do - and we don't know that, they're in your code. But if you can call built-in functions why can't you call a user-defined function?

Comment: we can't call built-in functions in this instance, anyway, i just need to find functions ```anumb``` and ```fraction```

Comment: As I wrote in the above comment: if your app supports `with` clause and your DBMS is not ancient then you may declare these functions locally and use *exactly the same* code as you do in SQL Developer or PL/SQL package. Just obtain other declarations and embed them in SQL statement. It should be tested for performance, but it's much easier to implement without too much reverse engineering. See an example in the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/odqfzEJw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH tmp AS (
    SELECT 
        CNUMBER
        , TRUNC(CNUMBER, 0) TR
        , (ROUND(CNUMBER, 2) - TRUNC(CNUMBER, 0)) * 100 FR
        , 'فقط' fakat
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            123332 CNUMBER
        FROM dual
    )
)

SELECT   
    CASE 
        WHEN CNUMBER > 999999999999.99 THEN 
            'Please enter a number less than 1 Trillion (1,000,000,000,000.00).' 
        ELSE 
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    CASE WHEN FR > 0 THEN
                        CASE WHEN TR = 0 THEN
                            CASE WHEN FR = 1 THEN
                                fraction(FR) || ' ' || fakat
                            ELSE
                                fraction(FR)
                            END
                        ELSE
                            anumb(TR) || ' و' || fraction(FR)
                        END
                    ELSE
                        anumb(TR) || ' ' || fakat 
                    END
                    , '   ', ' '
                )
                , '  ', ' '
            )
        END numb
FROM tmp;
```

Comment: so what i should do now is to find function ```anumb``` and ```fraction``` and pass parameter value ```cnumber``` somehow

Comment: I understand, You only want to transfor this function: numb to SQL version so there is, but what you do in anumb and franction idk and noone could know

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

You may ask for grant execute on that function if it is in the schema of a different user than that with which your application connects to the database.
Were it something rather simple, the logic might have been implemented using a case statement. Yet, in that function I can see calls to fraction and anumb, which I suppose are some other functions, which I cannot imagine what they are doing.

Comment: yeah you are right, I need to see those functions too to replaces resulted values as subqueries.